# Query DLFileEntry by metadata in Liferay 6.1

Tags: java, metadata, liferay-6

In Liferay 6.1 you can attach custom metadata fields to your DLFileEntries. How can I query DLFileEntries by its metadata contents from within the Java API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See relations between `DLFileEntry` and `DLFileEntryMetadata`:

[image]

from /liferay-sources/portal-impl/classes/com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/service.xml

You cat get with dynamic query the `DLFileEntryMetadata` and then maped this to `DLFileEntriy` with `dLFileEntryMetadata.getFileEntryId()`

Comment: When trying to create a query via `DynamicQuery query = DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(DLFileEntryMetadata.class);`, I get a NPE: `java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.hibernate.criterion.DetachedCriteria.forClass(DetachedCriteria.java:88) ~[na:na]
        at com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.DynamicQueryFactoryImpl.forClass(DynamicQueryFactoryImpl.java:35)`. Any ideas what might be the problem?

Comment: Providing the class loader helps: `DynamicQuery query = DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(DLFileEntryMetadata.class,
                PortalClassLoaderUtil.getClassLoader());`

Answer (score 0):

You can extend any Liferay domain object using [the Expando mechanism](http://www.liferay.com/web/raymond.auge/blog/-/blogs/715049). The different Expando services enable you to define additional fields on any object, DFFileEntry included, without needing to resort to the DynamicQuery functionality.